# My cache is not updated using @CachePut annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I searched for problem why `@CachePut` is not inserting data in my cache, but I didn't get it to work.

```java
@Cacheable(value = "employee")
public Map<String, String> getAllEmployeeIdWithFullNames() {
    return employeeRepo.getAllEmployeeIdWithFullNames();
}
```

And i used `@CachePut` like below:

```java
@CachePut(value = "employee") 
Map<String, String> saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    Map<String, String> employeeDetail = new HashMap<>();
    employeeRepo.save(employee);
    employeeDetail.put(employee.getUserId(), employee.getDisplayName());
    return employeeDetail;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine, only your understanding of how it works is flawed. The first call will cache a map with all the results, the other will cache a map with a single result for the employee as a key. So both methods cache different things and obviously it will not override or update single elements in the cache. That isn't how the cache abstraction works.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for reply, so do i need to add new result into existing cached value and then return in second case?

Comment: If you want to control the caching yourself, then do the caching yourself. Else you will be working/fighting something you shouldn't be using. You can still inject a `Cache` and use that. Or just clear the cache and it will be filled again when `getAllEmployeeIdWithFullNames` is called.

Comment: Where do you define the `Cache` you will be using? What's your implementation?

Comment: @MarioCodes i am using default cache which comes after enabling caching, i didnt configured any CacheManager like EHCache etc..

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, and it works fine. It's just that as Deinum says, you have two different things that you cache.

The method `getAllEmployeeIdWithFullNames()` returns a `Map<String, String>` which contains a `Map` of **all employees**.

The method `saveEmployee(Employee employee)` returns **another** `Map<String, String>`, which contains a `Map` **with the details of 1 employee**.

They're both the same *object type* `Map<String, String>` but they're not the same thing. My recommendation would be to use 2 different caches for 2 different things. An `employeesDetails` cache for the details, and an `allEmployees` cache for all your *employees*.